# Is it Possible to have Multiple Named Instances with No Default Instance?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, is it possible to install multiple named instances, and no default instance?

Comment: yes - you can -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is.  I have a dev server with multiple named instances (with multiple Sql Server versions) and no default instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however, if you name your instance `MSSQLServer`, that instance will become a default instance.